# JSON schema validation of optional fields using Golang

Tags: json, validation, go, option-type

Golang JSON schema validation libraries validate that required fields on the schema are present in the service request/response.

I need to validate that any field in a service request or response must be a property on the schema. If a property in the payload does not exist in the schema, the validation should fail.

For example: a *GET* response:

```
{
   "pet": "dog",
   "name": "Scooby",
   "licence": "123-123"
}
```

In my sample JSON schema, none of the fields are required. However, if I changed the field "pet" to "petBreed" in my service, it will not be caught by a JSON schema validator (e.g. https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema).

Making all fields required is not an option. Can anyone suggest a library in Go that will:

1. validate that all the response fields are in the schema
2. not fail if a field from the schema isn't in the response

Comment: If I understad you, you want to know if the JSON payload contains others fields that are not defined in you schema, right ?

Comment: Yes. I need the validation to fail if there are extra fields in the payload that aren't defined by the schema for example: typos, didn't update schema when we changed the JSON response payload.

Comment: Unmarshal to e.g. map[string]interface{} and check the keys. Dead simple, no tooling needed.

Comment: Yeah I'll probably go with what Volker proposed. Maybe you can find a lib that can give you all the fields of a JSON schema, and you compare those with the fields of your payload unmarshaled to a map.

Comment: Though operationally simple, checking this externally to JSON schema when it already supports that is a form of [information loss](http://wiki.c2.com/?InformationLoss)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON Schema defines [`additionalProperties`](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.20) for this purpose, something like this schema should work:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties":{
        "pet": ...,
        "name": ...,
        "license": ...,
    },
}
```

This is [implemented](https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=additionalProperties&type=) but not documented as such in `gojsonschema`.

Note that `additionalProperties` is a schema, not just a boolean, i.e. you can do arbitrary validation of unknown properties, not just disallow them.

Comment: Thank you. This was the most helpful solution and simplest to implement.